# How can I search in another language?

Tags: i18n-l10n, search

I have 2 languages in my site and a search view for **property search**
and I am using the Search API module.

When I try to search in English (default language), the search is working.
But when I try to search in the another language the search is not working.

I am searching by tittle.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using entity translation for translating the content, you will have to install the [Search API Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_et) module.

> *Search API Entity Translation* module provides multilingual support for the [*Search API*](https://drupal.org/project/search_api) module through integration with [*Entity Translation*](https://drupal.org/project/entity_translation).

This module provides a new index type : "multilingual node index", similar to the "default node index" which is provided by default by Search API.
You can use this to create the views and they will honor the language selected from the language switcher.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help @Ajits .
but i want to ask you some thing ,after creating the "multilingual node index" i changed the language to the second language (arabic) and i searched then the result that i got its the same that i want but its in the English not in Arabic its back to the default language !
So ... what should i edit in the search view to make the result shown in Current user's language ?

Comment: @WaseeemAlfarra Are you sure you are creating a new view with the "default multilingual node index" and not "multilingual node index"?

Comment: mmmmm...@Ajits . i created a view with "multilingual node index" not the  "default multilingual node index" !!

Comment: @WaseeemAlfarra I'm sorry! Cancel my previous comment. It should have been - Are you sure you are creating a new view with the "default multilingual node index" and not "default node index"?

Comment: don't worry my friend . am now creating a view with "default multilingual node index" ...

Comment: @WaseeemAlfarra Cool. That should resolve the issue then.

Comment: dude nothing happened still not working with arabic version :(