# why the search result shown in default language only ?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, search

i have a multilingual site with 2 languages and i have a search view , the search view works well in (english) and give me the result but when am changing the language to the second one ( arabic ) its give me the same result that i want but in english !!

English version:

[image]

Arabic version:

[image]

any suggestion to solve this problem ?

Comment: Check my answer here : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/210814/6461

Comment: @AjitS i checked it before but nothing happened dude check my comment under your answer please

Answer (score 0):

You should add a filter "Indexed node: language" and set it to "Current user language". This should be enough to ensure the results are shown in the current language.

Comment: Dude i add a filter "Content: Language (= Current user's language)" but nothing happened ! its take me to the same english result not the arabic one !

Comment: Have you reindexed? Have you cleared the cache?
How are the nodes translated?

Comment: yeah dude i reindexed and cleared the cache.i translated by Multilingual content @web-beest